# Как сделать UI, который можно масштабировать, но у виджетов позиции заданы точными координатами

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlayout

У меня есть несколько виджетов (два `QLabel`, `QLineEdit` и `QTimeEdit`). 
Я хочу, чтобы при изменении размеров окна они масштабировались в соответствии с изменениями, но при этом они должны оставаться на тех же местах относительно друг друга. Т.е. я хочу, чтобы, например, между двумя `QLabel` было одно и то же масштабируемое пустое пространство и т.д.

Прилагаю код всего проекта, само интересующее меня окно находится в классе `AppendWindow()`, которое наследует UI от класса `Ui_Append()`.

```
from sys import argv, exit
from os import remove
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QInputDialog, QMessageBox, QCalendarWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(891, 574)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 128, 64))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 128, 64))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 128, 64))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 128, 64))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 411, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 100, 361, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 240, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 360, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 440, 271, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 430, 101, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 150, 361, 351))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 20, 361, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(250, 30, 30);")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 891, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "DiaNotes"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Текущий пользователь"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Создать нового пользователя"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата записи:          01.01.2021"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Изменить дату"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить новое значение"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Построить график"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Среднее значение:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0.0"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить текущего пользователя"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистить"))




class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lable_2 = self.label_2
        self.w2 = CalendarWindow(self)
        self.w3 = AppendWindow(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.new_user)

        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.dellete_user)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.change_data)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.append_note)

        try:
            f = open('notes.sqlite', mode='r')
            f.close()
            con = sqlite3.connect('notes.sqlite')
            cur = con.cursor()
            users = cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM users""").fetchall()
            if len(users) == 0:
                remove('notes.sqlite')
                raise Exception
        except Exception:
            con = sqlite3.connect('notes.sqlite')
            cur = con.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE users (name text, id int)""")
            except Exception:
                pass
            cur.execute("""INSERT INTO users VALUES ('default_user', 1)""")
            con.commit()
            try:
                cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE note (user int, data text, time text, value float)""")
            except Exception:
                pass
            cur.execute("""INSERT INTO note VALUES (1, '01.01.2021', '0:00', 5.0)""")
            con.commit()
        con = sqlite3.connect('notes.sqlite')
        cur = con.cursor()
        users = cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM users""").fetchall()
        users = list(map(lambda x: x[0], users))
        self.comboBox.addItems(users)

    def new_user(self):
        name, ok_pressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Введите имя",
                                                "Введите имя нового пользователя")
        if ok_pressed:
            self.comboBox.addItem(name)
            self.comboBox.setCurrentText(name)
            con = sqlite3.connect('notes.sqlite')
            cur = con.cursor()
            ind = cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM users""").fetchall()
            ind = 1 + int(ind[-1][-1])
            cur.execute("""INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?)""", (name, ind))
            con.commit()

    def dellete_user(self):
        a = []
        for i in range(self.comboBox.count()):
            a.append(self.comboBox.itemText(i))
        if len(a) > 1:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Вы уверены?")
            ok = msgBox.addButton('да', QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
            msgBox.addButton('нет', QMessageBox.RejectRole)
            msgBox.setText("Вы действительно хотите удалить нынешнего пользователя?")
            msgBox.exec_()
            if msgBox.clickedButton() == ok:
                ind = self.comboBox.currentIndex()
                us = self.comboBox.currentText()
                con = sqlite3.connect('notes.sqlite')
                cur = con.cursor()
                res = cur.execute("""DELETE FROM note WHERE user = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ?)""", (us,))
                res = cur.execute("""DELETE FROM users WHERE name = ?""", (us,))
                con.commit()
                self.comboBox.removeItem(ind)
        else:
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
            msgBox.setWindowTitle("Ошибка")
            msgBox.addButton('ок', QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
            msgBox.setText("В списке всего один пользователь, его нельзя удалить. "
                           "Если вы хотите удалить этого пользователя, то создайте "
                           "нового, а после удалите этого")
            msgBox.exec_()

    def change_data(self):
        self.w2.show()

    def append_note(self):
        self.w3.show()


class Ui_Calendar(object):
    def setupUi(self, CalendarWindow):
        CalendarWindow.resize(574, 574)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(CalendarWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(37, 74, 500, 500))
        self.calendar.setObjectName("calendarWidget")

        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Подтвердить", self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(207, 25, 160, 40))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)

        CalendarWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class CalendarWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Calendar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalendarWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Выберите дату')

        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.change)

    def change(self):
        data = self.calendar.selectedDate().getDate()
        data = list(data)
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i] < 10:
                data[i] = '0' + str(data[i])
        data = str(data[2]) + '.' + str(data[1]) + '.' + str(data[0])
        self.parent.lable_2.setText('Дата записи:          ' + data)


class Ui_Append(object):
    def setupUi(self, AppendWindow):
        AppendWindow.resize(500, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(AppendWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.time = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.time.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 75, 170, 50))
        self.time.setObjectName("timeEditWidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.time.setFont(font)

        self.lable_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lable_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 170, 40))
        self.lable_1.setObjectName("lable_1Widget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lable_1.setFont(font)
        self.lable_1.setText('Выберите время')

        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 75, 170, 50))
        self.line.setObjectName("lineEditWidget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.line.setFont(font)

        self.lable_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lable_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 40, 170, 40))
        self.lable_2.setObjectName("lable_2Widget")
        font = QtGui.QFont('Times new roman', 16)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.lable_2.setFont(font)
        self.lable_2.setText('Введите значение')

        AppendWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)


class AppendWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Append):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AppendWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Новая запись')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование фиксированной геометрии - редко бывает хорошей идеей.
Менеджеры компоновки, такие как `QGridLayout`, гарантируют, что ваш интерфейс
всегда оптимизирован для любого разрешения окна, принимая во внимание шрифт и стили,
которые все виджеты используют для вычисления своего размера,
и гарантируют, что они всегда правильно отображаются, не перекрывая друг друга.

```
from sys import argv, exit
#from os import remove
#import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QInputDialog, \
    QMessageBox, QCalendarWidget, QGridLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(891, 574)
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 128, 64))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 128, 64))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 128, 64))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 128, 64))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 411, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setWordWrap(False)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 100, 361, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 240, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 360, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 440, 271, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 430, 101, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 150, 361, 351))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 20, 361, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(250, 30, 30);")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 411, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 891, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "DiaNotes"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Текущий пользователь"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Создать нового пользователя"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата записи:          01.01.2021"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Изменить дату"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить новое значение"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Построить график"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Среднее значение:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0.0"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить текущего пользователя"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Очистить"))


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(20, 20, 20, 20)
        self.grid.setHorizontalSpacing(80)
        self.grid.setVerticalSpacing(20)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(3, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(4, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(5, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(6, 1)
        self.grid.setRowStretch(7, 1)
        
        self.pushButton_5.setMinimumHeight(41)
        self.comboBox.setMinimumHeight(41)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumHeight(41)
        self.pushButton_2.setMinimumHeight(41)
        self.pushButton_3.setMinimumHeight(41)
        self.pushButton_6.setMinimumHeight(41)
        self.pushButton_4.setMinimumHeight(41)
        
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_5, 0, 4, 1, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 4, 1, 2) 
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.listView, 2, 4, 6, 2)  
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 3, 0, 1, 3)        
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 4, 0, 1, 3)        
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_6, 5, 0, 1, 3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 6, 0, 1, 3)        
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_4, 7, 0, 1, 2)  
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label_5, 7, 2, 1, 1)        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваше решение - не совсем то, чего я хотел, но оно помогло мне понять, как решить мою проблему. Спасибо